# How Do I convert IO String to a String

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, io

I have a text file with the following data:

```
3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

I want to essentially extract this data and return it in the form:

```
["3", "7 4", "2 4 6", "8 5 9 3"]
```

I used `readFile` to get the entire file as a single string, and then used lines to parse the individual line based on the `'\n'` character. I tried doing this but the problem I'm getting is that `readFile` returns `IO String`, but I want `String` instead. Here's the code:

```
readLines :: FilePath -> [String]
readLines str = do
                  file <- readFile str
                  let list = lines (file :: String) 
                  list
```

How do I deal with this problem?

Comment: You don't; this should be the first thing you learn about `IO` types. You don't get the data *out*; you build *new* IO actions by (e.g) binding the value to a function using `>>=`.

Comment: I understand that now. Can you elaborate a bit on the binding part?

Comment: `readLines "foo.txt" >>= someFunction` would be an IO action that, when executed, executes the action provided by `readLines "foo.txt"`, takes the resulting list, and passes it to `someFunction`. (`someFunction` itself has to be a function that returns an `IO` action. *You* never actually get to see the list read from `foo.txt`, but `someFunction` does.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `IO` is to *prevent* you from extracting data from I/O operations. Instead, your function will *also* return an IO action that, when executed at *runtime*, will produce a list of values.

```
readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines str = do
                   file <- readFile str
                   let list = lines (file :: String)
                   return list
```

or more simply, because `IO` (like any monad) is a functor,

```
readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines str = lines <$> readFile str
```

Comment: That makes sense. My end goal is to take the output from readLines and read the individual strings inside and create a list of [Ints].
i.e., ["3", "7 4", "2 4 6", "8 5 9 3"] turns into [[3], [7, 4], [2, 4, 6], [8, 5, 9, 3]].

But the problem is that I can't perform list operations on IO [String] if that makes sense.

Comment: Indeed. Say you want the first element of the list. If it *were* a `[String]` value, you could use `head` (we'll ignore the separate problem of dealing with empty lists). But since it's an `IO [String]`, you can only create yet *another* `IO` action of type `IO String` with, say, `head (readFile "foo.txt")`. Ultimately, every Haskell program is just an exercise in creating a single `IO ()` action to be executed at runtime.

Comment: @DanielMcAllister: what you'll do will look like `do lines <- readLines file; print (listOperation lines)`.